# Acessar sub-tabelas em uma tabela lua

Tags: loop, lua

Como eu leio uma subtabela dentro de uma tabela? Tentei retornar o valor com a função a seguir mas deu errado.

```
name = {"Lowes", "Renata", "Titia", "Maria"}

health = {}

posx = {}

posy = {}

posz = {}

players = {name, health, posx, posy, posz}




for id, i in pairs(players) do

    print(id.." - "..tostring(players.name))

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa definir a referencia na table(key, value):

```
name   = {"Lowes", "Renata", "Titia", "Maria"}
health = {}
posx   = {}
posy   = {}
posz   = {}

players = {["name"]=name, ["health"]=health, ["posx"]=posx, ["posy"]=posy, ["posz"]=posz}

for key, value in pairs(players) do
    print("players["..key.."]")
    for k, v in pairs(players[key]) do
       print(k.." -> "..v)
    end
 end
```

**EDIT**

```
online_players = {}
users = {"Lowes", "Renata", "Titia", "Maria"}

function create_player(name)
    return { name = name }
end

function add_attr(player, attr, value)
    player[attr] = value
end

-- lista todos os jogadores
for _, value in pairs(users) do

    --inicializa o jogador
    player = create_player(value);

    --adiciona os demais atributos do jogador
    add_attr(player, "health", 10)
    add_attr(player, "posx", math.random(1,10))
    add_attr(player, "posy", math.random(1,10))
    add_attr(player, "posz", math.random(1,10))
    add_attr(player, "custom", { age = math.random(1,60) })

    table.insert(online_players, player)
end

-- exibe os attributos dos jogadores
for _, player in pairs(online_players) do

    print("-- Player Attributes --")
    print("Name: "..player.name)
    print("Health: "..player.health)
    print("PosX: "..player.posx)
    print("PosY: "..player.posy)
    print("PosZ: "..player.posy)
    print("Custom: "..player.custom.age)
    print("")

end
```

Você também pode pegar todos os atributos de cada jogador de forma dinâmica utilizando o loop com pairs().

Comment: Entendi, mas o que eu quero fazer é o seguinte: criar uma função que "adiciona" novos chars na tabela e uma outra função que busca o nome desse char e retorna os valores. Tentei o que você me passou e consegui ter uma idéia.

Comment: O que eu não consegui (no código antigo) foi transformar uma string em variavel, pois iria criar uma tabela separada para cada jogador.

Comment: Acho que entendi, vou editar com um exemplo. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo. Só mais uma coisa, você consegue me explicar o que significa pairs, ipairs e pairsbykeys? E por que for _,? Obrigado. :)

Comment: O _ no for é apenas uma representação de uma variável que quero ignorar, no caso não quero usar a "key" que o pairs() retorna. Sobre a diferença entre as funções acredito que é uma questão de ordenação, quais elementos serão retornados primeiro no loop. Acho que esse link deve te ajudar: http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.10

Comment: Por que usar o `add_attr`? `player.health = 10` não funcionaria?

Comment: add_attr é apenas pra demonstrar como criar um atributo de forma dinâmica. É totalmente desnecessário a utilização dessa função.

Answer (score -1):

Tentei isso aqui:

```
players = {}

sit = {'name', 'health', 'posx', 'posy', 'posz'}

name = {"Lowes", "Renata", "Titia", "Maria"}

health = {100, 90, 80, 70}

posx = {}

posy = {}

posz = {}

table.insert(players, name)
table.insert(players, health)
table.insert(players, posx)
table.insert(players, posy)
table.insert(players, posz)

for k = 1, #players do
    for id, i in pairs(players[k]) do
        print(sit[k].." - "..players[k][id])
    end
    print('')
end
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).